# How to properly alert certain variable lastname and firstname in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am working with airtable.com database. Here I am trying to display of a record of a particular table where table id is 101.

Everything works fine as records are displayed.

Here is my issue: I need to alert **lastname** and  **firstname** of that record so I have added:

```
alert(record.lastname);
alert(record.firstname);
```

but nothing is alerted.

Here is the code that successfully displayed records:

```
 function RecordList1() {
 const base = useBase();
 const table = base.getTableByNameIfExists('my-tablename-here');
 // grab all the records from that table
 const records = useRecords(table);   
const recordSearch = records.filter(record => record.id == '101');
//alert(record.lastname);
//alert(record.firstname);

     // render a list of records:
     return (
         <ul>
             {recordSearch.map(record => {
                 return <li key={record.id}>{record.id} -- {record.lastname} ---- {record.firstname}</li>
             })}
         </ul>
     );
 }
```

Comment: It should be `alert(recordSearch.lastname)` instead of `alert(record.lastname)`?

Comment: it alerts undefined

Comment: alert(record.lastname) will alerts undefined because variable record is not defined.

Comment: `alert(recordSearch.lastname)` also says undefined

Comment: `recordSearch` is an array so you should do like this `alert(recordSearch[0].lastname)`

Comment: Thanks. you can update it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` function returns an array so alert line should be like this.
`alert(recordSearch[0].lastname)`